# How can I make a link in IE using base64 encoding method?

Tags: internet-explorer, base64, data-uri

I am generating a base64 gif on the fly and am trying to make a link to a new page to open a full size version of the gif. This works in chrome, but in IE, only the img thumbnail shows. When someone clicks on the link in IE, a blank page opens.

Any thoughts?

Thanks

Matt

```
echo '<a href="data:image/gif;base64,'. $data. '" target=_blank>';
echo '<img src="data:image/gif;base64,'. $data . '" width="200"/></a>';
```

Comment: What version of IE are you using?

Comment: So far I have just used IE 9. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

According to [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme#Disadvantages) you cannot use data uri for navigation in IE.

> - Internet Explorer through version 7 (approximately 5% of web traffic as of September 2011), lacks support. However this can be overcome by serving browser specific content.<sup>[[6](http://www.7cynics.com/webdesign/css/css-inline-images-data-uri.html)]</sup>
> - Internet Explorer 8 limits data URIs to a maximum length of 32 KB. (Internet Explorer 9 does not have this limitation)<sup>[[4](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc848897%28VS.85%29.aspx)][[3](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2010/09/15/ie9-beta-minor-change-list.aspx)]</sup>
> - In IE 8 and 9 data URIs can only be used for images, but not for navigation or Javascript generated file downloads. <sup>[[7](http://www.google.com/search?q=ie%20data%20uri%20supported%20site%3amicrosoft.com&btnI=1)]</sup>

Comment: I had seen the first 2 bullet points but not the third. That would explain it. Thanks for pointing that out Musa.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Java, you would create a servlet decoder. Like this: https://gist.github.com/sjpuas/6217394 This works me in all IE versiones

With jquery replace url images like this

```
if ($.browser.msie && $.browser.version == "6.0") {
                $("img[src*=base64]").each(function (i, img) {
                    var base64 = $(img).attr("src").split("base64,")[1];
                    var encoded = encodeURIComponent(base64);
                    $(img).attr("src", "/myApp/base64Servlet?base64=" + encoded);
                });
            }
```

Comment: Wouldn't this easily hit the max url length of 2083 chars on IE?