# Embedded base64 pdf won't display in IE when using iframe

Tags: html, pdf, iframe, embed

I wish to display a pdf file which is embedded using base64 encoding in an html.
Below is the code I have written for this. The pdf file is displayed in Chrome and firefox but not in Internet Explorer .

Any idea how to get it working in IE? Adobe Reader plugin is properly working in IE for me.

```
<iframe src="data:application/pdf;base64,baseEncodedString"></iframe>
```

I am not able to paste the base encoded string because of character limits.But it is of size 401676 characters.

Comment: IE has restrictions when it comes to showing elements with base64. Have a look at some of the comments on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12791952/how-can-i-make-a-link-in-ie-using-base64-encoding-method

Comment: Why would you base64-encode it in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

Aside from "it" being a terrible solution, here is what I would do:

```
<iframe src="/unbase64.php?mime=application/pdf&str=baseEncodedString"></iframe>
```

and then

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: " . $_GET["mime"]);
echo base64_decode($_GET["str"]);
?>
```

Stupid and will probably hit the maximum URL length often, but it works in principle.